# Multiday parking in San Francisco

Tags: usa, car-rentals, automobiles, california, san-francisco

I'm taking a road trip round California, with a four night stay in San Francisco. I will have a rental car for the duration of my stay but don't want to drive in San Francisco, apart from arriving and departing.

What is my best option for parking? I would prefer to park in a garage for the four nights but I'm not sure if garages allow this, or how much they would charge.

I've looked at this https://californiaparking.com/555-jackson-financial-district.shtml which allows me to reserve a space but not sure if it's legit.

I'm traveling from the UK and staying in the North Beach area.

Comment: Have you looked into the possibility of returning your rental car in SF and hiring another four days later?

Comment: @DJClayworth It becomes very expensive as I am currently picking up/dropping off at LAX so it would become two rentals both with a one way fee.

Comment: What does your hotel or host advise?

Comment: Unless a garage or lot has a specific policy of disallowing overnight parking, they'll be happy to take your money. At the very least, you can certainly park at the airport and take the train into the city. But "best" wil be subjective. Best for convenience? Safety? Cost?

Comment: @choster convenience. Don't want to make an unnecessary trip out to the airport.

Comment: If SF is your first or last port of call there is a good train that runs between SF and LA.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm going SF -> Santa Cruz -> Big Sur -> San Luis Obispo -> Santa Barbera over the next week so no.

Comment: if you're renting from the UK it's very likely there will be no one-way fee.  At least price it out as 2 rental, adding in parking/etc, to make sure it's not the best option.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend obtaining a long term parking permit at one of the various BART (Bay Area Rapid Transit) Stations in the San Francisco Bay Area.  As of August 2019 the daily rate is $7 for all stations where parking is available, which is far lower than any garage parking spaces you will find in metro San Francisco.  It should be noted that none of the BART stations in SF proper (Embarcadero to Balboa Park) have any parking facilities.

Once parked, depending on your station of choice, it will cost you between $3 and $7 for a one-way trip to the downtown San Francisco stations on the BART system.

Related links:

[BART airport/long-term parking permit reservations](https://www.select-a-spot.com/bart/reservations/facilities/?type=long_term)

[Fares, schedules, maps available at www.bart.gov](https://www.bart.gov/)

Answer (score 1):

I have built a [san francisco parking](https://www.spotangels.com/san-francisco) map for exactly this purpose.
If you don't want to pay for parking, you can see the streets where you can leave the car for more than a few days but be aware that you are not supposed to park on-street for more than 72h. 
If you are ok to pay, you can compare all the prices for on-street and off-street parking and can even book a garage.

Answer (score 0):

Enforcement of parking limits on public streets in SF is notoriously strict and persistent. If you park longer than permitted, it's certain you'll get an expensive ticket and it's possible your car will be towed and impounded, costing a lot of time and money to retrieve.

Off-street parking is a better bet.

Source: I live an hour away, lots of visits to SF, BTDT.